# How to optimize memory usage when switching Scenes with Gluon JavaFX

Tags: javafx, ram, javafxports, memory-optimization, gluon

**Increasingly High RAM Usage When Switching Between JavaFX Scenes**

Please can you explain as I have been experiencing high memory usage with my Gluon javaFx application when switching between scenes with the following code:

```
Stage stage = (Stage) AnchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ShopMenuPage.fxml"));
Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
Scene scene = new Scene(root, visualBounds.getWidth(), visualBounds.getHeight());
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Every time a scene is closed it does not release the full resources mainly the RAM and so accumulates with every window open and close resulting in the app crashing.

Comment: Where are you testing the application, desktop or mobile (android/iOS)?

Comment: The issue occurred when testing on Andriod with a Samsung Galaxy s4. Through some trouble shooting I realized that the images I was using were high resolution images. Once I changed some of the images with lower resolutions the RAM usage after switching between scenes decreased from around 300MB to 110MB on the phone. I am hoping to get the RAM usage permanently below 100MB to accommodate older phones and for smoother functioning. Thus I would appreciate any tips to help achieve this.

Comment: Good to know. Anyway, you should have a look at Gluon's `View` concept using Charm [library](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/2.0.0/#_glisten_apis). It will allow you switching views without actually changing scenes all the time.